# UnderscoreJS Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

In my Backbone view I have:

`noteTemplate: _.template($('#note-template').html()),`

Which is throwing this error. The template is:

```
<script type="text/template" id="note-template">
    <div class="reminder">
        <div class="reminder-hover">
            <div class="title"><%= title %></div>
            <div class="created">Created 3 days ago <span class="pull-right"> In 3 hours</span></div>
        </div>
        <span class="id" style="display: none;"><%= id %></span>
    </div>
</script>
```

I am confused because this works in my console:

`>> _.template($('#note-template').html());`
`function (n){return e.call(this,n,w)}`

Here is the the full code:

```
App.Views.Index = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("div.reminders"),
    todays : $("span.today"),
    tomorrows : $("span.tomorrow"),
    weeks : $("span.week"),
    all_times : $("span.all-time"),

    noteTemplate: _.template($('#note-template').html()),


    events: {
        "click .reminder" : "editNote",
        "click .newNote"  : "newNote"
    },

    initialize : function() { 
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.notes = this.options.notes;
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },

    render : function() {
        // Hide things related to editing a note 
        this.$("[name=content]").hide().val("");
        this.$("[name=title]").hide().val("");
        this.$("save1").hide();
        this.$("close1").hide();

        // Fill in content
        this.$el.html( this.noteTemplate( this.model.toJSON() ) );
        this.$todays.html( collection.getTodays.length );
        this.$tomorrows.html( collection.getTomorrows.length );
        this.$weeks.html( collection.getWeeks.length );
        this.$all_times.html( collection.getAllTimes.length );
        return this;
    },

    editNote : function() {
        this.goTo("notes/"+this.model.id);
    },

    newNote : function(){
        this.goTo("newNote");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rather than trying to cache the note template HTML when you define the method, do it when you initialize the view.

```
initialize : function() { 
    // ...
    this.nodeTemplate = _.template($('#note-template').html());
}
```

It's highly likely that you're defining the View before the DOM (and thus the template) is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is move the tag script above of call view , like this (I'm using jade)

```
script#page-thumb(type='text/template')
    .page-thumb-container.relative
      .page-thumb
        .image
          figure
            img(src='{{ image }}' , width='80px',height='60px' , data-id='{{ id }}')
          span.title {{ title }}
      .page-dragger.absolute

script(src='js/src/views/PageThumbView.js')
```